# Which test is appropriate when testing between nested groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, ordinal-data, model-comparison

Imagine that we want to analyze the outcome of a variable $Y$. The variable $Y$ represents the number of test passed, going from 1 to 7.
I want to know if $Y$ varies among different groups, for example different age, time points, gender, etc... .

I first thought about a chi-square test of independence but the problem is, for example, when an individual belongs to the group $Y=3$, then he belongs to the group $Y=2$, $Y=1$, and $Y=0$ too. So the chi-squared is not appropriate in this case.

There is no problem for me to conduct multiple tests, e.g., one for $Y$ in function of the age and one for $Y$ in function of the gender. So either a statistical model or a statistical test is suitable.

I also thought about Kruskal-Wallis or ANOVA, but in this case $Y$ must be continuous, which is not the case.

Comment: You seem to have an ordinal response variable, $1,2,\dotsc, 7$ So try ordinal regression, search this site!

Comment: Thank you, however regression is not really appropriate in my case because I do not have a lot of samples.